# How to exit from git stash show -p command?

Tags: git

i wanted to see stashed files so i entered

```
git stash show -p
```

now Im stucked in those files , how can i exit that command in terminal?

I tried clikcing

```
 ctrl + C
```

entered exit but still not getting out

Answer (score 2):

Git has output its text and it's now being displayed in a pager utility. Likely, and the default in a lot of cases, this is a program called `less`.

Press <kbd>q</kbd> (lower case Q) to quit `less` and exit back to the command line.